# Get correct value between 3 values based on language

Tags: python

I have a fairly simple question but yet I don't know what the best and shortest solution to my problem is.

Just for example, I have these variables, `name_nl`, `name_fr` and `name_en`.

Based on language priority (en, nl, fr) I'd like to end up with only one field that I will put in my API.

So if `name_en` is empty, it should give me `name_nl` and if that one is empty aswell it should give me `name_fr`.

So for example:
`name_en = ''` 
`name_nl = 'België'`
`name_fr = 'Belgique'`

> Desired outcome --> België

`name_en = ''` 
`name_nl = ''`
`name_fr = Belgique`

> Desired outcome --> Belgique

As a python rookie, I would just work with if statements, but because there are a lot more fields then just "name", I don't wan't to write a massive amount of code.

any tips?

Comment: I'd consider using a dictionary for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the full structure of the OP's code this may or may not be useful.

```
name_en = '' 
name_nl = 'België'
name_fr = 'Belgique'

print(name_en or name_nl or name_fr)

name_en = '' 
name_nl = ''
name_fr = 'Belgique'

print(name_en or name_nl or name_fr)
```

**Output:**

```
België
Belgique
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```py
def get_next(values):
    next(s for s in values if s)

print(get_next([name_en, name_nl, name_fr]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I'd suggest to solve the issue, with some changes based on specific needs:

```
class Word:
    langPriority = ['en', 'nl', 'fr']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.translations = kwargs
    
    @property
    def get(self):
        for lang in self.langPriority:
            try:
                if tr := self.translations[lang]:
                    return tr
            except KeyError:
                continue

name = Word(en = '', nl = 'België', fr = 'Belgique')

print(name.get)
```